# How to enlarge pdf link stack size?

Tags: luatex, links

I got this error:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pdf link stack size=10]

I cannot reproduce this error with demo code.

I would like to understand what is it this:

`pdf link stack size`

I cannot find any information on it in internet.

Update I:
I'm using Lualatex and I tried to use `directlua{ pdf_max_link_level = 20 }` as Werner proposed in comments

Update II:
I found that it was `\acrfull` command inside `\chapter{XXX \acrfull{YYY} ZZZ}`. Meanwhile it was ok before. The question still rests, how this problem could be adressed without deleting anything.

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full minimal example that shows this problem. That makes it a lot easier to help with your problem

Comment: @daleif As I wrote, unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this problem with a simple example...I will need to send half of the thesis to do so.

Comment: Then take a copy of all your thesis code, and start reducing (or out comment) the code. That is how the rest of us debug stuff like this. Do you have nested hyperlinks?

Comment: You can use `lipsum` package to add dumb text instead of the sensitive content of your tesis.

Comment: You are compiling with LuaLaTeX? Perhaps you can just add `\directlua{
  pdf_max_link_level = 20
}` to your preamble somewhere and things will work out... I don't know.

Comment: @Werner, I does not change anything. I mean this command does not change the error output, I still get [pdf link stack size=10]. I spent a lot of time to find what could cause this problem. I delete all \ref, all \acrhosrt and \acrfull. It helps when I start to reduce the size of text, but is sounds ridiculous, what I say.

Comment: @saldenisov doesn't that edit show you have nested hyperlinks, presumably in the TOC? The link to the chapter, containing a link til the acr stuff. Probably it is better to use an unlinked acr in the title.

Comment: Now that you narrowed down the problem: can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see in the sources this is just set in the c part of the code as

```
source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/pdf/pdftypes.h
```

which sets

```
 # define pdf_max_link_level 10  /* maximum depth of link nesting */
```

as a `# define` it is a C pre-processor constant not which will just be compiled in to the source as 10, so not changeable without recompiling the luatex binary program.

That said, 10 levels of nested link would be really odd (what user interface would you want for such a nesting?) So arranging your macros not to nest the links would be preferable to extending this stack.